# How to use custom $index which is genrated by a custom track by in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In most of the case, I just use $index for operations and to achieve uniqueness of records during curd operations

```
 <p ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index ">{{ $index }}</p>
```

but how I can access my custom index generated by track, as show below

```
 <p ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by contacts.name  ">{{ how to use this ($index not giving this to me ) }}</p>
```

Is there any way to do this? I need to do this, because old $index can't deal with multiple filters.

Comment: You don't need to use `track by $index` to get the index, you can use `$index` without using `track by`. Could you please explain what is `custom index` in your case?

Comment: if you do _'track by **x.y**'_ your custom index is nothing else but **x.y** which you can access everywhere in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<p ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index " ng-init="firstIndex = $index" >{{ firstIndex }}
    <p ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index " ng-init="secondIndex = $index">{{ secondIndex }}</p>
</p>
```

Comment: all i want to replace angular js default index by my custom id

Comment: @ShailendraSharma custom id means you want to start ng-repeat with specific id?